# Flutter splash screen error - Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator. How can I solve this error

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

Edit: (main.dart)
Added Sentry which actually starts the app

```
 Future<void> main() async {
   await SentryFlutter.init(
    (options) {
      options.dsn = _sentryDSN;
      // Set tracesSampleRate to 1.0 to capture 100% of        transactions for performance monitoring.
      // We recommend adjusting this value in production.
      options.tracesSampleRate = _sentryTracesSampleRate;
      options.attachStacktrace = true;
      options.enableAppLifecycleBreadcrumbs = true;
      },
   appRunner: () => runApp(const SplashScreen()),
  );

   // or define SENTRY_DSN via Dart environment variable (--dart-define)
  }
```

New to flutter, creating a splash screen to an app that was built with MaterialApp but getting an error. HOw can I solve this without a onPress function

Error:
[image]

Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.
The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget.)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:loopcycle/screens/loopcycle_main.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SplashScreen> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _navigateToMainApp();
}

void _navigateToMainApp() async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 2000), () {
    Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const LoopcycleMainApp()));
  });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    home: Builder(
      builder: (context) => const Center(
            child: Text("test"),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I changed the solution after you provided more information about the code.

This error is happening because you are using a context that does not have a `Navigator` in it, this is happening probrably because the widget that you are getting the context is parent of the `MaterialApp()` widget, to solve it you should create another widget that is a child of the `MaterialApp()` instead of using the parent widget, let me give you an example instead:

```
void main() {
    runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => SomeWidget(),
          ),
       ),
        child: Container(
          height: 300,
          width: 300,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This may give an error because you are using the context of a widget that is the parent of the `MaterialApp()` widget, to solve it just create another widget that is a child of `MaterialApp()`.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: AnotherWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class AnotherWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const AnotherWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => SomeWidget(),
          ),
        ),
        child: Container(
          height: 300,
          width: 300,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I was playing with your code, and fixed it for you, and there are basically two ways to solve it, you can create a `MaterialApp()` before calling the `SplashScreen()` in the `runApp()` function like so:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sentry_flutter/sentry_flutter.dart';
import 'package:loopcycle/screens/loopcycle_main.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  await SentryFlutter.init(
    (options) {
      options.dsn = _sentryDSN;
      // Set tracesSampleRate to 1.0 to capture 100% of        transactions for performance monitoring.
      // We recommend adjusting this value in production.
      options.tracesSampleRate = _sentryTracesSampleRate;
      options.attachStacktrace = true;
      options.enableAppLifecycleBreadcrumbs = true;
    },
    appRunner: () => runApp(
      const MaterialApp(
        home: SplashScreen(),
      ),
    ),
  );

  // or define SENTRY_DSN via Dart environment variable (--dart-define)
}

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SplashScreen> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _navigateToMainApp();
  }

  void _navigateToMainApp() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 2000), () {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const LoopcycleMainApp()));
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Builder(
          builder: (context) => const Center(
                child: Text("test"),
              )),
    );
  }
}
```

Or you can create an intermediate widget to hold the `MaterialApp()` and then inside this widget you can call `SplashScreen()`, like so:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sentry_flutter/sentry_flutter.dart';
import 'package:loopcycle/screens/loopcycle_main.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  await SentryFlutter.init(
    (options) {
      options.dsn = _sentryDSN;
      // Set tracesSampleRate to 1.0 to capture 100% of        transactions for performance monitoring.
      // We recommend adjusting this value in production.
      options.tracesSampleRate = _sentryTracesSampleRate;
      options.attachStacktrace = true;
      options.enableAppLifecycleBreadcrumbs = true;
    },
    appRunner: () => runApp(const MyApp()),
  );

  // or define SENTRY_DSN via Dart environment variable (--dart-define)
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: SplashScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SplashScreen> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _navigateToMainApp();
  }

  void _navigateToMainApp() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 2000), () {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const LoopcycleMainApp()));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Builder(
          builder: (context) => const Center(
                child: Text("test"),
              )),
    );
  }
}
```

In this second solution, the intermediate widget is the `MyApp()` widget, and in my opinion, I consider this solution as being the best one for your problem, because if you ever wanted to load a different screen based on the different states, for example:

If a user is signed in you load a home page, and if a user is not signed in you load a sign up page.

Doing this, or anything similar is much easier when you have this intermediate widget that holds the `MaterialApp()`, and you can even create some logic to integrate the Splash Screen too, but I don't know what you are trying to achieve, so pick the solution you find the best for your problem.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to mention the app starts with a sentry setup that runs the splash screen. I am nit sure if that is relevant but I tried this but it still throws an error in the Navigator.

Comment: No problem, I was able to make it work again after you provided new informations about your code, I am gonna edit my answer.